# Cannot access mysql by command line on Zend server on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, command-line, zend-server

I recently installed the latest Zend Server CE 5.6.0 SP4 on Windows 7 complete with php and mysql.
At first the Zend Server wouldn't work as I think there was some conflict with ports with my Zonealarm firewall. I deactivated the firewall, rebooted tried again and it worked so then reactivated the firewall. Not sure if the firewall has now found an alternative port. I don't really know much about those things. I think the ports it's on are 80 and 10061 but not too sure.

Anyway, I'm working through a PHP/Mysql book where it shows how to connect to the mysql database using the command line without a password. The first suggestion was:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\MySQL51\bin" -u root

That didn't work so I manually navigated to the MySQL51\bin folder then typed mysql.exe -u root. It then gave an error Error 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL on 'localhost' 10061

I tried turning the firewall off and trying again but still no luck.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks for any help

Gary

Comment: Update: I've tried accessing phpMyAdmin page on Zend Server using the username 'root' and 'zend' and I get the message Error 2002: Cannot log in to the MySQL server. I can't recall being offered the opportunity to set up a username and password specific to the MySQL server. The only one I set up was for Zend Server itself.

Comment: Update: After searching for solutions on forums I have changed the password for the 'root' user on the config.inc.php file and saved it. It was previously '' empty and had 'AllowNopassword'=true below. I seemed to get a step further on the command line at c:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\MySQL51\bin>. After entering mysql -u root -p password, a prompt 'Enter password:' came up where I re-entered the password but obtained the same Error 2003...Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\MySQL51\bin>mysqld --console
121024 21:17:12 [Warning] '--default-character-set' is deprecated and will be re
moved in a future release. Please use '--character-set-server' instead.
121024 21:17:12 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121024 21:17:12  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
121024 21:17:12 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on por
t: 3306 ?
121024 21:17:12 [ERROR] Aborting

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old post, it was one of the top hits searching for this problem. I found a solution that works on current MySql55 installation under ZEND. In the Zend installation folder (on Windows, hopefully same on others), Zend\MySql55\bin there's a file "MySQLInstanceConfig.exe".
If you run that, it let's you force a change to the password, and then (for me) the command line worked.